# Donut-shaped / inverse mask in Phaser

Tags: html5-canvas, phaser-framework, pixi.js

I am trying to get a donut-shaped mask in Phaser (essentially the inverse of a regular mask). The mask shape is dynamic so it needs to be a Phaser.Graphics polygon object.

**Desired result:**

*The blue shape is the sprite I want to mask, the hole in it is the mask itself.*

[image: Desired result]

I've searched the Phaser and Pixi v2 documentation and forums - found nothing though. Anybody who knows how I can do this?

---

If it is not possible, I am thinking of dividing the mask up into eight polygons:

[image: Possible workaround]

How sound is that idea? Is that going to be expensive or would it be ok? Or any other ways to achieve this?